# Class does not implement its superclass's required members

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I updated to Xcode 6 beta 5 today and noticed I received errors in nearly all of my subclasses of Apple's classes.

The error states:

> Class 'x' does not implement its superclass's required members

Here is one example I picked because this class is currently pretty lightweight so it will be easy to post.

```
class InfoBar: SKSpriteNode  { //Error message here

    let team: Team
    let healthBar: SKSpriteNode

    init(team: Team, size: CGSize) {
        self.team = team
        if self.team == Team.TeamGood {
            healthBar = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size:size)
        }
        else {
            healthBar = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size:size)
        }
        super.init(texture:nil, color: UIColor.darkGrayColor(), size: size)

        self.addChild(healthBar)

    }

}
```

So my question is, why am I receiving this error, and how can I fix it? What is it that I am not implementing? I'm calling a designated initializer.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

From an Apple employee on the Developer Forums:

> "A way to declare to the compiler and the built program that you really
>   don't want to be NSCoding-compatible is to do something like this:"

```
required init(coder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}
```

If you know you don't want to be NSCoding compliant, this is an option. I've taken this approach with a lot of my SpriteKit code, as I know I won't be loading it from a storyboard.

---

Another option you can take which works rather well is to implement the method as a convenience init, like so:

```
convenience required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(stringParam: "", intParam: 5)
}
```

Note the call to an initializer in `self`. This allows you to only have to use dummy values for the parameters, as opposed to all non-optional properties, while avoiding throwing a fatal error.

---

The third option of course is to implement the method while calling super, and initialize all of your non-optional properties. You should take this approach if the object is a view being loaded from a storyboard:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    foo = "some string"
    bar = 9001

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: The second option is useless in most real-life cases, though. Take, for example, my required initializer `init(collection:MPMediaItemCollection)`. You must supply a real media item collection; that is the point of this class. This class simply cannot be instantiated without one. It is going to analyze the collection and initialize a dozen instance variables. That is the whole point of this being the one and only designated initializer! Thus, `init(coder:)` has no meaningful (or even meaningless) MPMediaItemCollection to supply here; only the `fatalError` approach is right.

Comment: @matt Correct, one or the other option will work better in different situations.

Comment: Right, and I did discover and consider the second option independently, and sometimes it will make sense. For example I could have declared my d.i. `init(collection:MPMediaItemCollection!)`. That would allow `init(coder:)` to pass nil. But then I realized: no, now you are just fooling the compiler. Passing nil is not acceptable, so throw the `fatalError` and move on. :)

Comment: I know this question and its answers are kind of old now, but I've posted a new answer which addresses some points that I think are crucial to actually understand this error which weren't addressed by any of the existing answers.

Comment: Good answer. I agree with you that understanding that Swift doesn't always inherit super initializers is essential to understanding this pattern.

Answer (score 77):

There are two absolutely **crucial** pieces of Swift-specific information that are missing from the existing answers which I think help clear this up completely.

1. If a protocol specifies an initializer as a required method, that initializer must be marked using Swift's `required` keyword.
2. Swift has a special set of inheritance rules regarding `init` methods.

The **tl;dr** is this:

> If you implement any initializers, you are no longer inheriting any of the superclass's designated initializers.

<sub>The only initializers, if any, that you will inherit, are super class convenience initializers that point to a designated initializer which you happened to override.</sub>

So... ready for the long version?

---

#### Swift has a special set of inheritance rules regarding `init` methods.

I know this was the second of two points I made, but we can't understand the first point, or why the `required` keyword even exists until we understand this point.  Once we understand this point, the other one becomes pretty obvious.

<sub>All of the information I cover in this section of this answer is from Apple's documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).</sub>

From the Apple docs:

> **Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default.** Swift’s approach prevents a situation in which a simple initializer from a superclass is inherited by a more specialized subclass and is used to create a new instance of the subclass that is not fully or correctly initialized.

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

So, straight from the Apple docs right there, we see that Swift subclasses will not always (and usually don't) inherit their superclass's `init` methods.

**So, when do they inherit from their superclass?**

There are two rules that define when a subclass inherits `init` methods from its parent.  From the Apple docs:

> **Rule 1**
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Rule 2 isn't particularly relevant to this conversation because `SKSpriteNode`'s `init(coder: NSCoder)` is unlikely to be a convenience method.

So, your `InfoBar` class was inheriting the `required` initializer right up until the point that you added `init(team: Team, size: CGSize)`.

If you were to have not provided this `init` method and instead made your `InfoBar`'s added properties optional or provided them with default values, then you'd have still been inheriting `SKSpriteNode`'s `init(coder: NSCoder)`.  However, when we added our own custom initializer, we stopped inheriting our superclass's designated initializers (and [convenience initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36612507/2792531) which didn't point to initializers we implemented).

So, as a simplistic example, I present this:

```
class Foo {
    var foo: String
    init(foo: String) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    var bar: String
    init(foo: String, bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
        super.init(foo: foo)
    }
}


let x = Bar(foo: "Foo")
```

Which presents the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'bar' in call.

[image]

If this were Objective-C, it'd have no problem inheriting.  If we initialized a `Bar` with `initWithFoo:` in Objective-C, the `self.bar` property would simply be `nil`.  It's probably not great, but it's a perfectly *valid* state for the object to be in.  It's **not** a perfectly valid state for the Swift object to be in.  `self.bar` is not an optional and cannot be `nil`.

Again, the only way we inherit initializers is by not providing our own.  So if we try to inherit by deleting `Bar`'s `init(foo: String, bar: String)`, as such:

```
class Bar: Foo {
    var bar: String
}
```

Now we're back to inheriting (sort of), but this won't compile... and the error message explains exactly why we don't inherit superclass `init` methods:

> **Issue:** Class 'Bar' has no initializers
>
> **Fix-It:** Stored property 'bar' without initializers prevents synthesized initializers

If we've added stored properties in our subclass, there's no possible Swift way to create a valid instance of our subclass with the superclass initializers which couldn't possibly know about our subclass's stored properties.

---

#### Okay, well, why do I have to implement `init(coder: NSCoder)` at all?  Why is it `required`?

Swift's `init` methods may play by a special set of inheritance rules, but protocol conformance is still inherited down the chain.  If a parent class conforms to a protocol, its subclasses must to conform to that protocol.

Ordinarily, this isn't a problem, because most protocols only require methods which don't play by special inheritance rules in Swift, so if you're inheriting from a class that conforms to a protocol, you're also inheriting all of the methods or properties that allow the class to satisfy protocol conformance.

However, remember, Swift's `init` methods play by a special set of rules and aren't always inherited.  Because of this, a class that conforms to a protocol which requires special `init` methods (such as `NSCoding`) requires that the class mark those `init` methods as `required`.

Consider this example:

```
protocol InitProtocol {
    init(foo: Int)
}

class ConformingClass: InitProtocol {
    var foo: Int
    init(foo: Int) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile.  It generates the following warning:

> **Issue:** Initializer requirement 'init(foo:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in non-final class 'ConformingClass'
>
> **Fix-It:** Insert required

It wants me to make the `init(foo: Int)` initializer required.  I could also make it happy by making the class `final` (meaning the class can't be inherited from).

So, what happens if I subclass?  From this point, if I subclass, I'm fine.  If I add any initializers though, I am suddenly no longer inheriting `init(foo:)`.  This is problematic because now I'm no longer conforming to the `InitProtocol`.  I can't subclass from a class that conforms to a protocol and then suddenly decide I no longer want to conform to that protocol.  I've inherited protocol conformance, but because of the way Swift works with `init` method inheritance, I've not inherited part of what's required to conform to that protocol and I must implement it.

---

#### Okay, this all makes sense.  But why can't I get a more helpful error message?

Arguably, the error message might be more clear or better if it specified that your class was no longer conforming to the inherited `NSCoding` protocol and that to fix it you need to implement `init(coder: NSCoder)`.  Sure.

But Xcode simply can't generate that message because that actually won't always be the actual problem with not implementing or inheriting a required method.  There is at least one other reason to make `init` methods `required` besides protocol conformance, and that's factory methods.

If I want to write a proper factory method, I need to specify the return type to be `Self` (Swift's equivalent of Objective-C's `instanceType`).  But in order to do this, I actually need to use a `required` initializer method.

```
class Box {
    var size: CGSize
    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
    }

    class func factory() -> Self {
        return self.init(size: CGSizeZero)
    }
}
```

This generates the error:

> Constructing an object of class type 'Self' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer

[image]

It's basically the same problem.  If we subclass `Box`, our subclasses will inherit the class method `factory`.  So we could call `SubclassedBox.factory()`.  However, without the `required` keyword on the `init(size:)` method, `Box`'s subclasses are not guaranteed to inherit the `self.init(size:)` that `factory` is calling.

So we must make that method `required` if we want a factory method like this, and that means if our class implements a method like this, we'll have a `required` initializer method and we'll run into the exact same problems you've run into here with the `NSCoding` protocol.

---

Ultimately, it all boils down to the basic understanding that Swift's initializers play by a slightly different set of inheritance rules which means you're not guaranteed to inherit initializers from your superclass.  This happens because superclass initializers can't know about your new stored properties and they couldn't instantiate your object into a valid state.  But, for various reasons, a superclass might mark an initializer as `required`.  When it does, we can either employ one of the very specific scenarios by which we actually do inherit the `required` method, or we must implement it ourselves.

The main point here though is that if we're getting the error you see here, it means that your class isn't actually implementing the method at all.

As perhaps one final example to drill in the fact that Swift subclasses don't always inherit their parent's `init` methods (which I think is absolutely central to fully understanding this problem), consider this example:

```
class Foo {
    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    init(string: String) {
        super.init(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2)
        // do more nothing
    }
}

let f = Foo(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2)
let b = Bar(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2)
```

This fails to compile.

[image]

The error message it gives is a little misleading:

> Extra argument 'b' in call

But the point is, `Bar` doesn't inherit any of `Foo`'s `init` methods because it hasn't satisfied either of the two special cases for inheriting `init` methods from its parent class.

If this were Objective-C, we'd inherit that `init` with no problem, because Objective-C is perfectly happy not initializing objects' properties (though as a developer, you shouldn't have been happy with this).  In Swift, this simply will not do.  You can't have an invalid state, and inheriting superclass initializers can only lead to invalid object states.

Comment: Can you please explain what this sentence means or give an example?
"(and convenience initializers which didn't point to initializers we implemented)"

Comment: Brilliant answer! I wish more SO posts be about *why*, like this one, instead of only *how*.

Answer (score 56):

Why has this issue arisen? Well, the plain fact is that it has *always* been important (i.e. in Objective-C, since the day I started programming Cocoa back in Mac OS X 10.0) to deal with initializers that your class is not prepared to handle. The docs have always been quite clear about your responsibilities in this regard. But how many of us bothered to fulfill them, completely and to the letter? Probably none of us! And the compiler did not enforce them; it was all purely conventional.

For example, in my Objective-C view controller subclass with this designated initializer:

```
- (instancetype) initWithCollection: (MPMediaItemCollection*) coll;
```

...it is crucial that we be passed an actual media item collection: the instance simply cannot come into existence without one. But I have written no "stopper" to prevent someone from initializing me with bare-bones `init` instead. I *should* have written one (actually, properly speaking, I should have written an implementation of `initWithNibName:bundle:`, the inherited designated initializer); but I was too lazy to bother, because I "knew" I would never incorrectly initialize my own class that way. This left a gaping hole. In Objective-C, someone *can* call bare-bones `init`, leaving my ivars uninitialized, and we are up the creek without a paddle.

Swift, wonderfully, saves me from myself in most cases. As soon as I translated this app into Swift, the whole problem went away. Swift effectively creates a stopper for me! If `init(collection:MPMediaItemCollection)` is the only designated initializer declared in my class, I can't be initialized by calling bare-bones `init()`. It's a miracle!

What's happened in seed 5 is merely that the compiler has realized that the miracle doesn't work in the case of `init(coder:)`, because in theory an instance of this class could come from a nib, and the compiler can't prevent that — and when the nib loads, `init(coder:)` will be called. So the compiler makes you write the stopper explicitly. And quite right too.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. This really brings light into the matter.

Comment: An upvote to pasta12 for telling me how to make the compiler shut up, but an upvote to you too for cluing me in to what it was whining about in the first place.

Comment: Gaping hole or not, I was never going to call this init, so it is totally officious to force me to include it. Bloated code is an overhead that none of us need. It also now forces you to initialise your properties in both inits as well. Pointless!

Comment: @DanGreenfield No, it doesn't force you to initialize anything, because if you're never going to call it you just put in the `fatalError` stopper described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25128815/341994. Just make it a user Code Snippet and from now on you can just plop it in where it's needed. Takes half a second.

Comment: I know this question and its answers are kind of old now, but I've posted a new answer which addresses some points that I think are crucial to actually understand this error which weren't addressed by any of the existing answers.

Comment: @nhgrif Well, to be fair, the question didn't ask for the full back story. It was just about how to get out of this jam and move on. The full story is given in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_initializers

Answer (score 33):

add

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: This does work, but I don't think it is a bug. initializers are not inherited in swift (when your own initializer is declared) and this is marked with the required keyword. The only problem is that now I need to initialize ALL of my properties in this method for each one of my classes which will be a lot of wasted code as I don't use this at all. Or I will have to declare all of my properties as implicitly unwrapped optional types to bypass the initialization which I also don't want to do.

Comment: Yup! I realized as soon after saying it might be a bug, that it actually makes logical sense. I agree it will be a lot of wasted code, since like you I would never use this init method. Not sure about an elegant solution yet

Comment: I had the same issue. It make sense with "required init", but swift is not the "easy" language that I hoped for. All these "optional" are making the language more complex than required. And no support for DSL and AOP. I'm getting more and more disappointed.

Comment: Yes I completely agree. Lots of my properties are now declared as optionals because I'm forced into doing it, when really they shouldn't be allowed to be nil. Some are optionals because they legitimately should be optionals (meaning that nil IS a valid value). And then in classes where i'm not subclassing I don't need to use optionals, so things are getting very complex, and I can't seem to find a right coding style. Hopefully Apple figures something out.

Comment: It's unfortunately intentional, about halfway down on the release notes at http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_5_za4gu6/xcode_6_beta_5_release_notes.pdf it says, "The required modifier is written before every subclass implementation of a required
initializer. Required initializers can be satisfied by automatically inherited initializers.(17892840)!"

Comment: So how do we satisfy it through automatically inherited initializers? There are rules for how to do that, but I haven't been able to satisfy them apparently. Saying we can satisfy the required initializer implies that we shouldn't have to implement `initWithCoder:` in every dang class.

Comment: I think they mean that you can satisfy the required initializer by not declaring any initializer of your own, which would result in all initializers being inherited.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. Just read through the rules a little more closely, that is correct.

Comment: @BenKane I know this is old, but I've added an answer which hopefully fully explains initializer inheritance and the actual problem we're seeing here.

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks...I answered your other comment already. Should have @ mentioned you.