# UIView initializer swift Xcode 6 beta 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

xcode 6 beta 5

Error:

Class 'ClassName' does not implement its superclass's required members

on

```
    class ClassName:UIView
```

also showing an error

on

```
        init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            // Initialization code
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
```

Overriding declaration required an 'ovveride' keyword

I placed override before init, ovveride error was remove but superclass error was not

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members

Comment: I have explained this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members/25140956#25140956

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in *Xcode6 beta5* the `-init(coder:)` has became a required method to be overridden:

```
 class ClassName: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // ...
    }

    //

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Why we use required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // ...
    } and how?

Comment: and why other init are to be override?

Comment: if you want to init your view via unarchiving an existing object (after you archived it, of course), you can restore the view's previous state from the archive here.

Comment: you also need to flag the standard init method as overridden in your class.

Comment: I also think this answer needs further explanation. Please add it to the answer and not just in comments.