# Adding additional init code to an inherited initializer from superclass

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, object-initializers

I have a Swift UIView class (named HypnosisView) that draws a circle on the screen. The frame of the view is set to fill the screen. I would like to programmatically set the background color of the view upon initialization (so when an instance of the view is created it automatically has the specified background color). I was able to make this work with a convenience initializer, however I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this (or if in fact I'm doing this correctly). In an ideal scenario, I would like to just add a piece of code that sets the background: `self.background = UIColor.clearColor()` to the inherited `init(frame: CGRect)` method, so I don't have to write a whole new initializer just to set the background color. 
 Here is my convenience initializer method (what I'm currently using which works):

```
convenience init(rect: CGRect){
        self.init(frame: rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

and I call that method in the delegate like this:

```
var mainFrame = self.window!.bounds
var mainView = HypnosisView(rect: mainFrame)
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a convenience initializer? You already subclass UIView. In its **designated** initializer, set the background color. But it's basically exactly what you're doing (minus the convenience), and I don't see how you can make it any shorter. Your "whole new initializer" is simply a call to super and your own modifications.

Comment: @Rikkles I had tried overriding the designated initializer like this: `override init(frame: CGRect){ self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() <return key> super.init(frame: frame)}` and it threw the error: `Class "HypnosisView" does not implement its superclass's required members`, which is why I tried the convenience initializer. I'm still learning all this

Comment: Actually I take that back. If you use the convenience initializer it's the simplest. Because if you override `init(frame)`, you **also** must override `init(coder)` which creates more code for you. So in your case I think you've got the simplest solution. A convenience initializer that sets a property to a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, when wanting to customize the behavior of a UIView, it's often easier to use a `convenience` initializer as opposed to overriding a designated initializer.

For UIViews specifically, if you override the designated `init(frame aRect: CGRect)`, you are unfortunately also required to override `init(coder decoder: NSCoder!)` which is part of the `NSCoding` protocol. So generally if you just want to set a few properties to some default values, do as the original poster asked and create a convenience initializer that in turn calls `init(frame aRect: CGRect)`:

```
convenience init(rect: CGRect, bgColor: UIColor){
    self.init(frame: rect)
    self.backgroundColor = bgColor
}
```

For a discussion on getting rid of `NSCoding` compliance, see [Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members)

Comment: One question: what does it mean when you have two parameter names when you say `init(frame aRect: CGRect) `?

Comment: Means that externally the parameter is called `frame`, but internally to the function it's called `aRect`. See "External Parameter Names" in the Swift book.