# initWithNibName does not implement superclass - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, init

I'm trying to implement the Objective-C equiv. below when calling a view controller with a nib.

Objective C:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
        self.transitioningDelegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is where i am in swift so far:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
    self.transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

However i keep getting this error:

```
Class "ViewController" does not implement its superclass's required members
```

I thought the init method above was it required members?

Edit - Goes into more detail below:
[Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must implement base class required initializers. In your case you should add code bellow to your VC class:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Since Beta 5:

> The required modifier is written before every subclass implementation
>   of a required initializer. Required initializers can be satisfied by
>   automatically inherited initializers.

**Remarks:**

`required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) { ... }` should be added only if you override at least one `init` method in your class.

Comment: If you find that this solution doesn't work for you in Swift2, you have to make it optional.  
      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

CREDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087478/ios-9-errors-and-correct-conversion-to-swift-2