# iOS 9 errors and correct conversion to swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9

So after updating to iOS 9 and Swift 2 I had many errors in my project that even after clicking the convert automatically option didn't get fixed. Luckily most were pretty simple and I was able to figure them out but I have three major ones left. Is anyone able to help me out with these?

Thanks a lot!

Code chunk #1

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
    return attributesList
}
```

Error for chunk 1

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Code chunk #2

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Error for chunk 2

```
A non-failable initializer cannot chain to failable initializer 'init(coder:)' written with 'init?'
```

Code chunk #3

```
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Error for chunk 3

```
'(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void' is not convertible to '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'
```

EDIT: Now that number three is fixed (but still deprecated) I get this error underneath for this code:

Code:

```
var dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Error:

```
Extra argument 'error' in call
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` now returns `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?` not `[AnyObject]?` write:

   ```
   override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
   }
   ```
2. Super.init now is fallible `public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` it means It may return nil so you have to write:

   ```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }
   ```
3. Do not use explicit types in this case. Just write:

   ```
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) in

   }
   ```
4. Read about error handling because `try!` can let down your app :/

   ```
   try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
   ```

but **sendAsynchronousRequest was deprecated in iOS 9**

Comment: okay great thanks! But now I have an error below for #3... I edited the code above.

Comment: Great thanks again! 

However, now it won't get the parse data for the app and says "2015-10-12 11:48:28.682 FiveTest[2456:98960] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.8.2)"... Any idea what that's about?

Comment: @Echizzle yes. you have to use `https` instead of `http`

Comment: @Echizzle you need to edit your info plist and add the domain your app needs to access

Comment: @Echizzle besides that issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work