# DrawView crashes ios xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Just a newbie to the ios programming, and decided to start coding ios application using Xcode 6.1 swift language.

I created a new project. Then added a new Cocoa class DrawView. Then clicked main.storyboard main view and in the identity inspector put int he field class - DrawView.

Then I chose DrawView.swift - uncomment drawRect method and put into it

```
var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds)
```

and started a project, the problem is

> Path/DrawView.swift: 11: 11: fatal error: use of unimplemented
>   initializer 'init(coder:)' for class '_d_Quartz1.DrawView'

What shoud I do in oder to avoid this problem?

The entire code:

```
class DrawView: UIView {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
       var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the entire contents of `DrawView.swift`.

Answer (score -2):

You'r missing this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Just add this to your class, it should work.

Update:
Follow this link to get the detailed answer when to override this method:
[Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members)

Comment: This answer would be better if you could also explain _why_ it is needed. What the purpose of `initWithCoder` is compared to `initWithFrame`, etc.

Comment: Here's the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members

Comment: The real problem with this answer is that it won't fix the original problem, because Olexiy is loading his DrawView from a storyboard, which requires `init(coder:)` to be implemented properly, not stubbed with `fatalError`.  However, it's on the right track.  I'll remove my downvote if it's fixed.

Comment: Well, now in my log i have

<pre>fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/alex/Documents/Xcode/Projects/2d_Quartz1/DrawView.swift, line 19</pre>

Comment: if type something like this - the project starts normally

   init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }