# What are convenience required initializers in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128815/998117) that the user specifies a `convenience required init()`. What exactly does this mean?

I understand that the `required` keyword is used for overriding a superclass's designated initializer, but what does the `convenience required` declarative do?

Comment: Kindly help me improve my answer if it wasn't helpful? :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A convenience required initializer is an initializer that is enforced onto all subclasses but is not the designated initializer. This means that said initializer will eventually call a designated initializer in its initialization chain.

### Designated Initialisers

A designated initialiser is the canonical initializer for a class and the one which all required and convenience initialisers should call. The [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) say:

> Designated initializers are the primary initializers for a class. A
> designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by
> that class and calls an appropriate superclass initializer to continue
> the initialization process up the superclass chain.

### Convenience Initialisers

A convenience initialiser is an initializer that sets up certain configuration information on a class...conveniently. Documentation:

> Convenience initializers are secondary, supporting initializers for a
> class. You can define a convenience initializer to call a designated
> initializer from the same class as the convenience initializer with
> some of the designated initializer’s parameters set to default values.
> You can also define a convenience initializer to create an instance of
> that class for a specific use case or input value type.
>
> You do not have to provide convenience initializers if your class does
> not require them. Create convenience initializers whenever a shortcut
> to a common initialization pattern will save time or make
> initialization of the class clearer in intent

### Required Initialisers

Required initializers can be thought of as a binding contract between a parents interface and subsequent subclasses. Its your means of enforcing that all your children are aware of and implement a certain set of initialisers.

> Write the required modifier before the definition of a class
> initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must
> implement that initializer:

Comment: Thanks for the outline of the three types, but what does it mean when you *combine* convenience and required into a `convenience required` init?

Comment: It means (1) the initializer is not a designated initializer itself, and (2) subclasses are required to implement this initializer.

Comment: @GregParker that being said it is an interest notion of making a convenience initialiser required. Its like a "nice to have" being something you "have to have" :)

Comment: The `required` and `convenience` keywords are 100% independent of each other.  Using them in combination doesn't change anything about the semantics of each keyword when considered independently.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring required initialiser of class as convenience lets subclasses [easily inherit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222) it and thus ommit its implementation

```
protocol P {
    var some: Int! {get}
    init(some: Int)
}

class C: P {
    private(set) var some: Int!
    convenience required init(some: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.some = some
    }
}

class D: C {
    // no need in required init(some: Int)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class initializer can be marked with `required` to indicate that every subclass of the class must implement that initializer.

As a subclass, you can use a designated initializer or a convenience initializer to satisfy this requirement.