# initiliazation in Ios

Tags: ios, swift

when should we need to implement

```
required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatal error("NSCoding not supported")
}
```

I am not sure when should we add this implementation besides the normal initialazation that is already exist

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members

Answer (score 0):

If your developed some code or program that you don't wanted to compile then you can use NSCoding compatible.

for e.g I had use for SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

**Required Initialisers**

Required initializers can be thought of as a binding contract between a parents interface and subsequent subclasses. Its your means of enforcing that all your children are aware of and implement a certain set of initialisers.

`Write the required modifier before the definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must implement that initializer:`

In Short, we can say that in super class hierarchy any method have denoted by **required** then that enforced us to be implement in its subclass. so at that time need to implement it.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922694/what-are-convenience-required-initializers-in-swift?lq=1)!