# Why convenience keyword is even needed in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

Since Swift supports method and initializer overloading, you can put multiple `init` alongside each other and use whichever you deem convenient:

```
class Person {
    var name:String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    init() {
        self.name = "John"
    }
}
```

So why would `convenience` keyword even exist? What makes the following substantially better?

```
class Person {
    var name:String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "John")
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just reading through this in the documentation and got confused about it too. :/

Answer (score 264):

The existing answers only tell half of the `convenience` story.  The other half of the story, the half that none of the existing answers cover, answers the question Desmond has posted in the comments:

> Why would Swift force me to put `convenience` in front of my initializer just because I need to call `self.init` from it?`

I touched on it slightly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531), in which I cover *several* of Swift's initializer rules in details, but the main focus there was on the `required` word.  But that answer was still addressing something that's relevant to this question and this answer.  We have to understand how Swift initializer inheritance works.

Because Swift does not allow for uninitialized variables, you are not guaranteed to inherit all (or any) initializers from the class you inherit from.  If we subclass and add any uninitialized instance variables to our subclass, we have stopped inheriting initializers.  And until we add initializers of our own, the compiler will yell at us.

To be clear, an uninitialized instance variable is any instance variable which isn't given a default value (keeping in mind that optionals and implicitly unwrapped optionals automatically assume a default value of `nil`).

So in this case:

```
class Foo {
    var a: Int
}
```

`a` is an uninitialized instance variable. This will not compile unless we give `a` a default value:

```
class Foo {
    var a: Int = 0
}
```

or initialize `a` in an initializer method:

```
class Foo {
    var a: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}
```

Now, let's see what happens if we subclass `Foo`, shall we?

```
class Bar: Foo {
    var b: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int) {
        self.b = b
        super.init(a: a)
    }
}
```

Right?  We added a variable, and we added an initializer to set a value to `b` so it'll compile.  Depending on what language you're coming from, you might expect that `Bar` has inherited `Foo`'s initializer, `init(a: Int)`.  But it doesn't.  And how could it?  How does `Foo`'s `init(a: Int)` know how to assign a value to the `b` variable that `Bar` added?  It doesn't.  So we can't initialize a `Bar` instance with an initializer that can't initialize all of our values.

What does any of this have to do with `convenience`?

Well, let's look at [the rules on initializer inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> **Rule 1**
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Notice Rule 2, which mentions convenience initializers.

So what the `convenience` keyword *does* do is indicate to us which initializers *can be inherited* by subclasses that add instance variables without default values.

Let's take this example `Base` class:

```
class Base {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(a: 0, b: 0)
    }

    convenience init(a: Int) {
        self.init(a: a, b: 0)
    }

    convenience init(b: Int) {
        self.init(a: 0, b: b)
    }
}
```

Notice we have three `convenience` initializers here.  That means we have three initializers that can be inherited.  And we have one designated initializer (a designated initializer is simply any initializer that's not a convenience initializer).

We can instantiate instances of the base class in four different ways:

[image]

So, let's create a subclass.

```
class NonInheritor: Base {
    let c: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {
        self.c = c
        super.init(a: a, b: b)
    }
}
```

We're inheriting from `Base`.  We added our own instance variable and we didn't give it a default value, so we must add our own initializers.  We added one, `init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)`, but it doesn't match the signature of the `Base` class's designated initializer: `init(a: Int, b: Int)`.  That means, we're not inheriting *any* initializers from `Base`:

[image]

So, what would happen if we inherited from `Base`, but we went ahead and implemented an initializer that matched the designated initializer from `Base`?

```
class Inheritor: Base {
    let c: Int

    init(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {
        self.c = c
        super.init(a: a, b: b)
    }

    convenience override init(a: Int, b: Int) {
        self.init(a: a, b: b, c: 0)
    }
}
```

Now, in addition to the two initializers we implemented directly in this class, because we implemented an initializer matching `Base` class's designated initializer, we get to inherit all of `Base` class's `convenience` initializers:

[image]

The fact that the initializer with the matching signature is marked as `convenience` makes no difference here.  It only means that `Inheritor` has just one designated initializer.  So if we inherit from `Inheritor`, we'd just have to implement that one designated initializer, and then we'd inherit `Inheritor`'s convenience initializer, which in turn means we've implemented all of `Base`'s designated initializers and can inherit its `convenience` initializers.

Comment: @nhgrif "How does Foo's init(a: Int) know how to assign a value to the b variable that Bar added? It doesn't. So we can't initialize a Bar instance with an initializer that can't initialize all of our values."  Hi, nhgrif, I qoute your answer, I don't understand why Swift can't just inherit the init(a: Int) and add a int(b: int) in Subclass. excuse for the naive question. But I really want to know.

Comment: @SLN [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531) covers a lot on how Swift initializer inheritance works.

Comment: @SLN Because creating a Bar with `init(a: Int)` would leave `b` un-initialized.

Comment: @nhgrif Why is it necessary to reimplenent *all* of the super classes's designated initializers to unlock the convenience initializers? If only one of many superclass designated initializers were reimplemented, couldn't the compiler unlock only the  convenience initializers which use it?

Comment: @IanWarburton I don't know the answer to this particular "why".  Your logic in the second part of your comment seems sound to me, but the documentation clearly states that this is how it works, and throwing up an example of what you're asking about in a Playground confirms the behavior matches what is documented.

Comment: @IanWarburton I think the answer to your question is that it's a design issue. Yes, what you're saying could be done, but it would complicate the initialiser inheritance process a lot, and it wouldn't be clear what was available and what wasn't. Having a simple system like this makes the language easier to understand and work with. And it's already pretty complex as it is. Look how long it took to explain! Personally I think they achieved a well balanced design here. And thanks for the great post nhgrif you should be on the team to maintain or write the Swift book! Much clearer explanation.

Comment: Why the OP did not accept this answer? It perfectly explains why and when the `convenience` keyword is needed, and it does it in a superbly clear way. I would like the Apple documentation was equally clear..  +1

Comment: This answer taught me so much about initializers. Especially the Base Class example. Thank you @nhgrif

Comment: From what I experienced being part of Swift community, the fact that the language compilation is quite complicated comparing to most other compiled languages, many people in this community lost connection to what is a programmer API and what is a compiler API. Some decisions are really questionable and `convenience` keyword is one of them. I personally see no useful insight to have it in my code. Just as with `indirect` keyword for enums, `@escaping` closures and some other keywords.

Answer (score 9):

Mostly clarity.  From you second example,

```
init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}
```

is required or *designated*.  It has to initialize all your constants and variables.  Convenience initializers are optional, and can typically be used to make initializing easier.  For example, say your Person class has an optional variable gender:

```
var gender: Gender?
```

where Gender is an enum

```
enum Gender {
  case Male, Female
}
```

you could have convenience initializers like this

```
convenience init(maleWithName: String) {
   self.init(name: name)
   gender = .Male
}

convenience init(femaleWithName: String) {
   self.init(name: name)
   gender = .Female
}
```

Convenience initializers must call the *designated* or required initializers in them.  If your class is a subclass, it must call `super.init()`  within it's initialization.

Comment: So it would be perfectly obvious for the compiler what I'm trying to do with multiple initializers even without `convenience` keyword but Swift would still be bugging about it. That's not the kind of simplicity I was expecting from Apple =)

Comment: This answer doesn't answer anything. You said "clarity", but didn't explain how it makes anything clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Well, first thing comes to my mind is that it's used in class inheritance for  code organization and readability. Continuing with your `Person` class, think of a scenario like this

```
class Person{
    var name: String
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init(){
        self.init(name: "Unknown")
    }
}


class Employee: Person{
    var salary: Double
    init(name:String, salary:Double){
        self.salary = salary
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name:name, salary: 0)
    }
}

let employee1 = Employee() // {{name "Unknown"} salary 0}
let john = Employee(name: "John") // {{name "John"} salary 0}
let jane = Employee(name: "Jane", salary: 700) // {{name "Jane"} salary 700}
```

With convenience initializer I am able to create an `Employee()` object with no value, hence the word `convenience`

Comment: With `convenience` keywords taken away, wouldn't Swift get enough information to behave in the same exact way?

Comment: No, if you take away `convenience` keyword you can't initialize `Employee` object without any argument.

Comment: Specifically, calling `Employee()` calls the (inherited, due to `convenience`) initializer `init()`, which calls `self.init(name: "Unknown")`. `init(name: String)`, also a convenience initializer for `Employee`, calls the designated initializer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Swift 2.1 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), `convenience` initializers have to adhere to some specific rules:

1. A `convenience` initializer can only call intializers in the same
   class, not in super classes (only across, not up)
2. A `convenience` initializer has to call a designated initializer
   somewhere in the chain
3. A `convenience` initializer cannot change **ANY** property before it
   has called another initializer - whereas a designated initializer
   **has to** initialize properties that are introduced by the current class
   before calling another initializer.

By using the `convenience` keyword, the Swift compiler knows that it has to check for these conditions - otherwise it couldn't.

Comment: Arguably, the compiler could probably sort this out without the `convenience` keyword.

Comment: Moreover, your third point is misleading.  A convenience initializer can only change properties (and can't change `let` properties).  It cannot initialize properties.  A designated initializer has the responsibility of initializing all introduced properties before calling to a `super` designated initializer.

Comment: At least the convenience keyword makes it clear to the developer, it's also readability that counts (plus checking the initializer against the developer's expectations). Your second point is a good one, i changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A class can have more than one designated initializer. A convenience initializer is a secondary initializer that must call a designated initializer of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the points other users have explained here is my bit of understanding.

I strongly feel the connection between convenience initializer and extensions. As for me convenience initializers are most useful when I want to modify (in most cases make it short or easy) initialization of an existing class.

For example some third party class that you use has `init` with four parameters but in your application the last two have same value. To avoid more typing and make your code clean you could define a `convenience init` with only two parameters and inside it call `self.init` with last to parameters with default values.

Comment: Why would Swift force me to put `convenience` in front of my initializer just because I need to call `self.init` from it? This seems redundant and kinda inconvenient.