# Property 'self.myDelegate' not initialized at super.init - Delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, initializer

I am experimenting with Protocols and Delegates and I am stuck while initializing the delegate.

At the top my of my class, I tried  adding

```
protocol myDelegateProtocol {
   func clickedCellIndexPath(indexPath: Int)
}

class MyClass {

     var myDelegate : myDelegateProtocol


     override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setup()     // error 1
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)  // error 2
     }

}
```

It started giving errors for both init closures

> Both errors: `Property 'self.myDelegate' not initialized at super.init`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

---

If I try declaring it as `var myDelegate: myDelegateProtocol?`, it doesn't give that error, but it forces me to force unwrap `myDelegate!` and it returns nil at this point.

**Edit**: If I force it unwrap at the top, then I receive error in the following parts..

```
 ...
var myDelegate : myDelegateProtocol!

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {

    if let point = sender?.locationInView(collectionView) {
        print("Y")
        let clickedCell = collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)!.row

        print(clickedCell)  // prints

        self.myDelegate.clickedCellIndexPath(clickedCell) // error here
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**:

So my complete code..:

```
protocol myDelegateProtocol {
   func clickedCellIndexPath(indexPath: Int)
}

class MyClass {
     var myDelegate: KDRearrangableClickedCellDelegate!

     override init() {
         super.init()
         self.setup()
      }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
     }

    func setup() {
         if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
             let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
          }
     }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {

         if let point = sender?.locationInView(collectionView) {

             let clickedCell = collectionView!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)!.row
             print(clickedCell)

             self.myDelegate.clickedCellIndexPath(clickedCell)
         }
    }
```

And I receive this error at this point:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Some related reading on the topic can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36612507/2792531) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531).  Basically, you fundamentally don't understand how Swift's initializer's work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, because `myDelegate` is not initialized in `init`, you must make it optional. For example:

```
var myDelegate: KDRearrangableClickedCellDelegate?
```

Then when you need to use it, unwrap this optional, e.g.:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let point = sender.locationInView(collectionView) {
        if let clickedCell = collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)?.item {
            print(clickedCell)
            myDelegate?.clickedCellIndexPath(clickedCell)
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd recommend the use of an optional (`KDRearrangableClickedCellDelegate?`) rather than an implicitly unwrapped one (`KDRearrangableClickedCellDelegate!`), so that if you haven't yet set `myDelegate`, your app won't crash. Clearly, if you want `clickedCellIndexPath` to be called, you have to actually set `myDelegate`. I'm also doing optional binding of the `clickedCell`, so that if the tap wasn't on a cell, it won't crash. Also, I'm using `item` rather than `row`, as collection views generally don't use `item`/`section` rather than `row`/`section`.

You don't show us how you set `collectionView` nor how you set `myDelegate`, but for the above to work, you need to set both of those before the gestures can be handled correctly.

---

As an aside, I don't know what the relationship is between `MyClass` and its `myDelegate`, but often you make delegates `weak` to avoid strong reference cycles. To do that, define your protocol as a class protocol:

```
protocol myDelegateProtocol : class {
   func clickedCellIndexPath(indexPath: Int)
}
```

And then define your `myDelegate` to be `weak`:

```
weak var myDelegate: KDRearrangableClickedCellDelegate?
```

You only need to do this is if the object that will be the `myDelegate` for `MyClass` will, itself, maintain a strong reference to `MyClass`. If not, you may not need to make your delegate weak. It just depends upon your object model, which you haven't shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `myDelegate` as non-Optional, which means that it must be initialized in your `init()` methods *before* calling `super.init()`. If your `setup()` method is where you're assigning a value to `myDelegate` (which I'm guessing is the case, although you haven't included your `setup()`'s implementation here), then you need to call `setup()` *before* `super.init()`, and/or declare `myDelegate` to be Optional (with a '?').

Comment: Can you please add a code example in your answer to make it clear for me. I tried moving it in to both initialisers, but I couldn't make it work :/

Answer (score 0):

This is line that is causing the problem:

```
var myDelegate : myDelegateProtocol
```

myDelegate is declared as non-optional but you did not initialise
it in your init function.  If you are initialising it in your setup()
function, you need to change the declaration of myDelegate to like this.

```
var myDelegate : myDelegateProtocol!
```

Comment: I added an edit part in my question. When I change it to !, then it causes further problems. What am I missing? :/

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? like the setup function.
Just to be safe. You need to check if myDelegate is not null before call the function clickedCellIndexPath

Comment: When I try `print(clickedCell)`, it logs the integer value successfully. I am adding more code to my question

Comment: yep. but I meant  if  self.myDelegate { self.myDelegate.clickedCellIndexPath(clickedCell)  }

Comment: Please don't recommend [implicitly unwrapped optionals](https://metova.com/blog/dev/problem-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals/).

Comment: I put the code together in the question. Please tell me if you need to know more.. And thanks for the tip for checking, I am adding it now, too. I think it's about that the delegate doesn't seem to work. :/

Comment: I am not recommending.  I am just trying to help the guy with his programming question. Whether you use implicitly unwrapped options or not that is debatable.  And the fact that the compiler is allowing it is just a proof that there are just too many scenarios or design patterns that following strictly one rule just wont fix it.

And thank you for the downvote. appreciate it.

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting it (and I am highly grateful and appreciate your help). I tried checking if myDelegate is nil and it is! What may be the problem? (upvoted)