# Swift: how to avoid rewriting this init() in all inheriting classes?

Tags: swift

I have this class and protocol in a framework:

```
public protocol P {}

open class C {
    public init(_ p: P.Type) {
        //super.init() etc
    }
}
```

And in the project using this framework:

```
enum E: P {
    // cases...
}
```

The thing that bugs me is that for every class that inherits `C`, I need to define the same `init()` like this:

```
final class C1: C {
    init() {
        super.init(E.self)
    }
}

final class C2: C {
    init() {
        super.init(E.self)
    }
}

// etc...
```

Is there a way for me to declare this default `init` in my project, like using an extension this way:

```
extension C {
    // Declare the init(E.self) here somehow?
}
```

This way, I would simply call `C1()`, `C2()` etc without defining it in the subclass.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a protocol that contains the init, extend the protocol and provide a default implementation, and assign the protocol to C.

```
public protocol P {}

enum E: P {
}

protocol A {
    init(_ p: P.Type)
}

extension A {
    init(_ p: P.Type) {
        // Add a default implementation
        self.init(E.self)
    }
}

class C: A {
    // If you want to override, note you need to add `required`
    required init(_ p: P.Type) {
    }
}

class C1: C {
    // No need to init here
}
```

Or if you don't want another protocol, you will need a new class that implements the init and subclass C and have your C1 and C2 inherit this new class.
Its what is usually done when people create BaseUIViewController and make their UIViewControllers subclasses of this:

```
public protocol P {}

enum E: P {
}

class C {
    init(_ p: P.Type) {
    }
}

class CBase: C {
    // Override and provide default implementation
    override init(_ p: P.Type) {
        super.init(E.self)
    }
}

class C1: CBase {
    // No need to init here
}

class C2: CBase {
    // No need to init here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a [convenience initialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093773/169346)

```
extension C
{
    public convenience init()
    {
        self.init(E.self)
    }
}

let c1 = C1()
let c2 = C2()
```

Or you can put the convenience initialiser in the main definition of `C`.