# How do I create a class that requires an instance variable to be set?

Tags: swift

```
public class User : NSObject {
    var id: Int //will throw an error during build
    var name: String?
    override init(){
    }
    convenience init(id: Int, name: String?){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I want to create a user class.  The `id` should non-optional.  However, my above code does not work unless I change the line to:

`var id: Int = 0`

I don't want to do this.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You'll either have to set `id` in your `init()` or use the solution Fonix provided. Because right now, if you try: `let user = User()`, then `id` won't be initialized.

Comment: Related reading: [Class does not implement its superclass's required members](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the word `convenience`! Convenience is exactly the opposite of what you want. You want this to be a designated initializer. Like this:

```
public class User : NSObject {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    init(id: Int, name: String?){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }
}
```

This *forces* the creator of a User to supply an `id`, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User {
    let id: Int
    var name: String?

    init(id: Int, name: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

let user = User(id: 3) // works without errors
```

As you can see, I changed some things. You probably don't really need to subclass `NSObject`, and I don't think you'll want to change a user's `id` after initialisation, so it makes more sense to make it a `let` constant.

Comment: i dont see how you can make this assumption. i would say a struct is definitely not a good fit for a User object (in normal circumstancecs), since each time the user object is assigned, it will be copied (the nature of a struct in swift). so making changes to say `name` in one place will have no effect on the user object in another place.

Comment: That may be so, and in that case changing `struct` to `class` would solve that problem.

Comment: I guess you're right a `class` makes more sense here, I updated my answer.

Comment: and now you havnt solved the problem with the compile time error

Comment: There must be a reason why he's using a convenience initializer though?

Comment: Yea, well his example is kinda basic so it's hard to tell if he really needs a convenience initializer.

Comment: @Eendje Based on the asking history of this user, it's unlikely there's a *good* reason.