# Getting no initialisation error in swift class

Tags: swift, class, struct, initialization, nsuserdefaults

Hi am new to swift i am string to store user credential in user default from the struct  object in a LoginViewController. Below is my code,

```
class User: NSObject {
    //MARK: Properties
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var loginData: LoginData

    //MARK: Initialization
    init(name: String, email:String, loginData: LoginData) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.loginData = loginData
    }
}
```

Here LoginData is a structure

```
struct LoginData {
    var username: String
    var password: String
}
```

while submitting register data am assigning values as

```
let logindata = LoginData (username: username, password: password)        
let v = User(name: nameval, email: emailval, loginData:logindata)
```

In LoginViewContoller I have a switch button to save user credential to NSUserdefaults I created

```
var logindataValue: LoginData
```

And storing in user defaults as follows

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(logindataValue.username, forKey: "username")
defaults.setObject(logindataValue.password, forKey: "password")
defaults.synchronize()
```

But in LoginViewController class showing an error as “LoginViewController has no initializers”

How to prevent this  error? Is this the right approach to do in this scenario?

Comment: You provided a lot of irrelevant data about your various model objects, but didn't include almost anything for the one class that is actually giving you the error, the `LoginViewController`.  I'm guessing that it's missing because it's probably "too big", which means you didn't even attempt making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  But if you want some related reading regarding Swift initializers, I suggest you [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is complaining that you aren't initializing the `var logindataValue: LoginData` in your `LoginViewContoller`. You can solve this a couple of ways.

1. Make `logindataValue` an `Optional`:

In your `LoginViewController` change the definition of `logindataValue` to this:

```
var logindataValue: LoginData?
```

It will be given a default initial value of `nil`. You'll have to unwrap it when you use it, but that's okay.

2. Give `logindataValue` a different default value:

In your `LoginViewController` change the definition of `logindataValue` to this:

```
var logindataValue = LoginData(username: "", password: "")
```

I don't recommend this approach. It doesn't seem right to create an empty `LoginData` object with meaningless values. It would be better to use an `Optional` value. But if there is some other meaningful default value that you could give, then this might work.

3. Add an initializer for `LoginViewController`:

This is the most complicated, as it is not easy to create custom initializers for subclasses of `UIViewController`. You will have to add an initializer that includes a `logindataValue` parameter that you can use to initialize `logindataValue`. But you will also have to override `init?(coder: NSCoder)` which is a pain in the you-know-what and probably not what you need.

So my advice is to make `logindataValue` an `Optional`.

Comment: ... or... create an initializer.