# Swift: How to initialise a let constant in a UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I want the model to be passed in by the implementing developer and I want that to be mandatory.

```
let model: PagingTutorialModel

init(withModel model: PagingTutorialModel) {
    self.model = model
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Error: Property 'self.model' not initialised at super.init call

Comment: try with optional init `let model: PagingTutorialModel?`

Comment: No.  Please don't switch to optionals for the sake of appeasing the compiler unless an optional is actually the correct representation of your data.

Comment: [Recommended reading regarding init with coder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32108404/2792531).

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I'm using storyboards yes. Funny how saying that out loud now makes everything seem so clear. If I am using storyboards then the controller is initialised when the scene is segue'd to ... so assigning to a let constant during initialisation is simply not possible unless we avoid storyboards all together. Would you mind posting this as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: You could implement the `NSCoding` protocol for your `PagingTutorialModel` class and call `init(coder:)` on it...see http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that in `init?(coder:)` you also need to set the model. Depending of you setup, one solution could be to trap in `init?(coder:)`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Not implemented")
}
```

But doing so, you can't initialize this view controller from a storyboard. But in my opinion Storyboards are only for prototyping.

Answer (score 3):

View controllers cannot realistically have `let` values unless you're assign them a default value.

```
let foo = 3
```

The problem is, when we initialize view controllers from storyboards, iOS initializes the view controller with `init(coder:)`.  We don't have an opportunity to pass values in during initialization, so we cannot have `let` properties.